# Boolean values not changing? [C++]

Tags: c++

main:
https://github.com/MJGHD/Stacks./blob/master/main.cpp

```
//Imports needed libraries, headers and defines the size of the question and answer variables

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "lib/script.h"
#define STRING_SIZE 1000

//Initalises the temporary dummy variable and the question + answer variables
std::string questions[STRING_SIZE];
std::string answers[STRING_SIZE];

//Initalises showMainMenu function
void showMainMenu();


int main() {
    //Shows the main menu
    showMainMenu();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void showMainMenu() {
    std::cout << "Welcome to Stack.! To get started, type in the number from 1-4 that you desire!\n\n";
    std::cout << "1. Create new stack\n";
    std::cout << "2. Open existing stack\n";
    std::cout << "3. Export existing stack\n";
    std::cout << "4. Options\n\n";
    std::cout << "";
    //Assigns the user input to the dummy variable initalised earlier
    std::cin >> dummy.usrInput;
    //Reads the usrInput and figures out what the user wanted
    switch(dummy.usrInput){
        case 1:
            createNewStack();
        case 2:
            openExistingStack();
        case 3:
            exportExistingStack();
        case 4:
            showOptions();
        default:
            std::cout << "That was not a valid input. Press enter to continue... ";
            std::cin.get();
            clearScreen();
    }
}
```

script:
https://github.com/MJGHD/Stacks./blob/master/lib/script.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

struct usrOptions{
    bool autosave, randomisedCards;
    std::string autosaveOn, randomOn;
}option;

struct dummies{
    int usrInput;
}dummy;

inline void clearScreen(){
    #ifdef _WIN32
        std::system("cls");
    #else
        std::system ("clear");
    #endif
}

inline void saveUserStack(){

}

void createNewStack(){

}

void openExistingStack(){

}

void exportExistingStack(){

}

void showOptions(){
    clearScreen();
    switch(option.autosave){
        case 0:
            option.autosaveOn = "off";
        case 1:
            option.autosaveOn = "on";
    }
    switch(option.randomisedCards){
        case 0:
            option.randomOn = "off";
        case 1:
            option.randomOn = "on";
    }

    std::cout << "1. Autosave is currently " << option.autosaveOn;
    std::cout << "\n2. Randomised cards are currently " << option.randomOn;
    std::cout << "\n\nWhich option do you wish to change (please enter in the form of an integer): ";
    std::cin >> dummy.usrInput;
    switch(dummy.usrInput){
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Are you sure you wish to change the option for autosave? 0 = no 1 = yes: ";
            std::cin >> dummy.usrInput;
            switch(dummy.usrInput){
                case 0:
                    clearScreen();
                    showOptions();
                default:
                    switch(option.autosave){
                        case 0:
                            option.autosave = 1;
                        default:
                            option.autosave = 0;
                    }
                    showOptions();
                }
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Are you sure you wish to change the option for randomised cards? 0 = no 1 = yes: ";
            std::cin >> dummy.usrInput;
            switch(dummy.usrInput){
                case 0:
                    showOptions();
                default:
                    switch(option.randomisedCards){
                        case 0:
                            option.randomisedCards = 1;
                        case 1:
                            option.randomisedCards = 0;
                    }
                    showOptions();
            }
        default:
            showOptions();
    }    
    std::cout << "Autosave is currently " << option.autosaveOn;
}
```

For some reason, when I verify changes to the options, the values don't change, or at least the output stays the same.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be aware that questions should be self-contained (i.e.: They may contain external resources, but they should be answerable without them). You can try providing an [mcve].

Comment: Please extract a minimal example which you then post inline here. As it stands, your question is off-topic, please read the posting guidelines for further info. Also, tags should not be in the title, there's a reason there is a separate place for them.

Comment: What does "when I verify changes to the options" mean? What options are you talking about? How are you changing them? How are you verifying the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your problem, it appears that you are forgetting to add a break to each of your switch cases.

Please look at the below MSDN article on using switch
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a.aspx

If you are used to VB.NET, you may be used to case statements being self-contained. C requires a break, or else the logic will fall through to the next statements, even if the switch doesn't match.